# Newtons Binomial coefficient C++ algorithm

Tags: c++

So we have to calculate the Binomial coefficient using functions.
In order to do that I created one function for factorial calculus and another function that uses the latter to calculate the number of possible combinations. 
They both work well (were done in previous exercises) but for some reason eclipse stops working when I run my code now. It should take the number that the user enters (`j` in my code) and make make combinations with `i` (that starts from 0) until `i` equals `j`. Anyone has an idea?

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//factorial function
int fact(int a) {
    int resultat = 1;
    while (a > 0) {
        resultat = resultat * a;
        a = a - 1;
    }
    return resultat;
}

//combinations function
int combinaisons(int z, int y) {
    int c;
    c = ((fact(y)) / ((fact(z)) * (fact(y - z))));
    return c;
}

int main() {
    int i, j;
    cout << "Entrez le degree" << endl;
    cin >> j;
    while (j < 0) {
        cout << "Un nombre naturel svp!" << endl;
        cin >> j;
        i = 0;
    }
    //calculation of the binomial coefficient
    while (i != j) {
        cout << combinaisons(i, j) << endl;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A more definitive description of the error(s) you're getting is probably needed. Post error codes/messages if you can.

Comment: It says "project_name" stopped working. Just as any windows applications can freeze.

Comment: Your calculation algorithm is very bad - you calculate the whole factorial, so if `a = 20` or larger, then it will overflow the `int` type (`20! = 2432902008176640000 > 2^31 - 1`). There is a very easy solution: just use the recursive relation `C(n, k) = C(n-1, k-1) + C(n-1, k)`.

Comment: The purpose of this exercise was to show us how functions work. We can ignore variable issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You failed to initialize `i` when the user enters a correct value the first time.

Initializing `i` with its declaration should suffice.

Also you are not treating the case where `i == j`, afterall `binom(j,j) = binom(j,0)`

```
//change the condition
while (i <= j) {
        cout << combinaisons(i, j) << endl;
        i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I ran in another problem now. It only prints out 1, 3 ,3 when it should print 1, 3, 3, 1.

Answer (score 0):

In your main you have:

> int i, j;

If the **J** is 0, you never assign a value for **i**, because **while (j < 0)** is never true.

Then you use **j** and **i** like its a well determined behaviour, but no behaviour is defined for uninitialized variables (**i** in this case).

Making **while (i != j)** loop go forever, then hanging eclipse.

Possible solution:

> int i = 0, j = 0;

and remove the initialization of **i** variable from the loop.